# stats.f_oneway Scipy Anova returns 2 arrays with 4 values

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, anova

Trying to run one way Anova on data which looks approximately like this:

```
Year   | Diversity  |
2010   |   6        |
2010   |   8        |
...    |   ...      |
2011   |   10       |
...    |   ...      |
2019   |   7        |
```

There are 1827 rows, diversity values for various points within the range of each year. I am comparing the variance year on year. When I do

```
F, p = stats.f_oneway(df.loc[df["Year"] == 2010],
               df.loc[df["Year"] == 2011],
               df.loc[df["Year"] == 2012])
```

(Here I omitted the rest of the groups because this is very ugly but I couldn't figure out how else to pass the different groups for the Anova test). I get an array with 2 values each for F and p:

```
F: type float64, size (2,),
-2.588805281700000000e+11, 4.908743340532151223e+00
p: type float64, size (2,),
nan, 0.00774507
```

From what I read, I can't find anyone getting 2 arrays, it should be just one F value and one P value, I am doing something seriously wrong? 
(There are no zeroes or NANs in the df).

When I do:

```
mod = ols('Diversity ~ (Year)', data = df).fit()
mod.summary()
```

I get a normal Summary table, with F = 1.462, p = 0.227 (different to my attempts above).

Any ideas on my mess would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DataFrame has 2 columns, even after you slice it, thus you return 2 p-values and 2 F-values, one for the comparison of each column across samples. You should change each selection to only include the `'Diversity'` column, like:

```
df.loc[df['Year'] == 2010, 'Diversity']
```

If you just want to do an ANOVA for Diversity across all years in your sample, you can do this compactly with:

```
stats.f_oneway(*[s for idx, s in df.groupby('Year').Diversity])
```

---

#### MCVE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

l = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (50, 4))) for i in range(7)]
                                              # |
                                              # 4 cols, should get 4 p-vals/F-vals

stats.f_oneway(*l)
#F_onewayResult(statistic=array([0.70527759, 0.2291319 , 0.03545031, 0.02568242]), 
#                  pvalue=array([0.49563511, 0.79550711, 0.96517894, 0.97464894]))
                               #    col1         col2        col3       col4
```